# How to Reset Dock Items in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dock

By mistake I removed 3 items from my dock.

Now I want to reset all items as it was.

Is there an option to do this, as I don't even know which items were removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your Dock is meant to be customized, so don't worry about removing items.

If you do want to reset the Dock to its original configuration, launch Activity Monitor and navigate to `~/Library/Preferences/` in the Finder. Trash `com.apple.dock.db` and `com.apple.dock.plist`, then immediately quit the Dock from Activity Monitor.

You do this all at once with this command line (but note that it wll delete the files instead of trashing them, so **it is not reversible**). To do that, open Terminal from your Applications/Utilities folder.

On OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion:

```
rm  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist{,.lockfile}; killall Dock
```

On older versions:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.{db,plist}; killall Dock
```

Comment: I'm using Mavericks this worked for me `defaults delete com.apple.dock` and then `killall Dock`

Answer (score 4):

If you can't follow the instructions given by SidneySM here is what you would find in your default dock (from left to right).

- Dashboard
- Mail
- Safari
- iChat
- Address Book
- iCal
- Preview
- iTunes
- Spaces
- Times Machine
- System Preferences

Answer (score 0):

I did as the first guidance but it not worked on Snow Leopard 10.6. So I finished it manually as below:

1. Click to "Finder" and point to "Applications"
2. Select the expected items from the applications list and drag it to the Dock.
3. To remove it from Dock: Right Click the icon from Dock, then point to "Option" and
   select "Remove From Dock"

Note: You can do that one by one or with many selected items at the same time

Answer (score 0):

IF you're looking for the original icon layout in Mountain Lion as of Aug 13 it's in the following order:

- Finder
- Launchpad
- Mission Control
- Safari
- Mail
- Contacts
- Calendar
- Reminders
- Notes
- Messages
- FaceTime
- Photo Booth
- iPhoto
- iTunes
- App Store
- System Preferences
- Dock Resize Line
- Downloads
- Trash

Also doing this means you won't lose you're magnification and dock zoom options.

Hope this helps people and is what they are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

In OS X Yosemite, run these commands in Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock
```

then

```
killall Dock
```

That should fix it.